# How to get id from the checkbox to check if is checked or not in vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, vuex, vuejs3

```
<div>
  <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    class="delete-checkbox" 
    :id=this.products[index].sku  
    @click="setDelete(this.products[index].sku)" />
</div>
```

I'm building an vuex app and I try to start an event when this checkbox is checked but I don't know how to do this.

Can somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls check out following snippet:

```js
const demo = {
  data() {
    return {
      products: [{sku: 1}, {sku: 2}, {sku: 3}],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setDelete(id) {
      console.log('event fired for: ' + id)
    }
  },
};
Vue.createApp(demo).mount("#demo");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <li v-for="(product, idx) in products" :key="idx">
    <input type="checkbox" class="delete-checkbox" :id="product.sku" @click="setDelete(product.sku)">
  </li>
</div>
```